# Unable to handle the alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, protractor

HTML code:

```html
<div class="MuiGrid-root jss18 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-4" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;">
  <div class="MuiDialogTitle-root jss19" id="alert-dialog-title">
    <h2 class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h6">Sorry !
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="MuiDialogContent-root">
    <p class="MuiTypography-root MuiDialogContentText-root jss19 MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary" id="alert-dialog-description">Invalid User credentials.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="MuiDialogActions-root MuiDialogActions-spacing">
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button">
      <span class="MuiButton-label">OK
      </span>
      <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root">
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note : It's React js application

Test Script(Java Script):

```js
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Output:
Failed: no such alert

but when use the xpath for the "ok" button, it worked.

Comment: What behaviour do you want your website to have? Do you want the alert to be displayed when you press the button?

Comment: i need to click on the OK button which is displayed on the alert

Comment: it's not an alert. It's regular web element